# Jenkins Build Parameter - Windows File Path Not working

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am creating a parameterized jenkins build with following values. The issue here is LOCAL_REPO parameter is somehow not working, I mean maven command is not recognizing this value. But I can see the LOCAL_REPO value in echo. This parameter I am using to refer maven to local repository and have offline build.

```
 bat 'mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=${LOCAL_REPO} -o clean deploy'
```

[image]

Comment: Try using double quotes as shown here: `bat "mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=${LOCAL_REPO} -o clean deploy"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Technext comment, It is working fine!

By using double quotes

`bat "mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=${LOCAL_REPO} -o clean deploy"` – Technext 1 hour ago